# Which browsers/plugins block HttpReferer from being sent?

Tags: http-referer, refer

I am trying to interpret HttpReferer strings in our server logs. It seems like there is quite a high number of empty values.

I am wondering how many of these empty values are due to direct hits from people entering our URL directly into a browser and how many might be due to some kind of blocking utility that prevents the Referer from being sent.

I really have no idea how many people are using tools or browsers or 'anonymizers' that might block the refer. Any input?

Comment: How many of those are spiders? Are you looking at the user agent, too?

Comment: i actually have this data going into a database table and i screwed up the UserAgent logic somehow so UserAgent is all blank. i'll have to install a proper log mining tool, but I'm not even sure if referer is being logged in IIS

Answer (score 2):

I think a large proportion may actually be caused by ISPs' restrictions. I know my ISP (BT, in the UK) filters it out (probably at the router) which is bloody annoying at times.

As it turns out, the block is actually put in place by Zone Alarm, a software firewall, which is often supplied by ISPs.

Comment: seriously! wow. does anyone have any more information about that practice? how common is this practice. is this just a proxy server thing

Comment: Actually, I've done my ISP a slight disservice. The block is, in fact, put in by zone alarm (google "zone alarm block referer") which was supplied as part of the ISP's package.

Answer (score 2):

I personally disable it using "Web Developer" extension of Firefox, only because of some "helpful" sites that highlight the search terms that I used to get to that page.

Thanks, I am fully capable of installing a highlighter plugin, or search for the words inside your page.

Answer (score 2):

Opera has a quick toggle in the F12 menu that you can switch on "Send Referrer Information" or not to the site(s) you're surfing around.

Comment: interesting... so that accounts for 0.001% of my lost referers ;-)

Comment: I think it's more like 0.01% and creeping.

Comment: That is my default setting in any of my installed browsers…

Answer (score 2):

I used to log all this stuff in my blogging app - pretty much all bots never send referrer info.

You should be able to make an educated guess as to whether it's down to it being filtered out or just people entering the URL.

If the first hit has no referrer but the loading of images/CSS etc has referrer info then they just entered the URL directly.
If they only ever pull down HTML with no images or CSS they are most likely a bot (or using Lynx perhaps).
If they pull down HTML, images and CSS with no referrer then it's being filtered out.

Answer (score -2):

Some antivirus software is retarded and also started doing this for "security" reasons.

We had an email form that used referrer tracking to eliminate the gist of the random bot-spam an some people moaned that it didn't work.

Not entirely wonderful, but there are far more *good* uses of the referrer header than for just 'lets be evil and watch where people came from'  to legitimise it.

( Some antivirus packages have been known to stop email working altogether for instance, and the clients will ring you and tell you its your fault until you tell them to get rid of their rubbish i've never heard of that company before' antivirus  for the 40th time and they listen and their problem magically resolves )

#### Addendum on security

Referrer tracking is very useful for keeping state within a site. (Without needing cookies)

Referrer tracking is very useful to acknowledge that a users origin was from the site itself ( without needing cookies )

Though I see a legitimate privacy concern with leaking 3rd party sites leaking data via referrer, and the recipient seeing that.

So:

```
3rd-party => site  # referrer preferred blank
local     => local # referrer preferred kept
```

At least here you can easily distinguish between a "hotlink" from an external source and an internal link.

Also, because of this, cross-domain referrals from SSL websites are blocked by default by some browsers.

Comment: "antivirus software is retarded" IMHO there are more valid reasons to disable the referrer header than to send one. The concept behind my assumptions is called ["privacy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy). In fact you never ever should rely on the referrer when building some software.