# About what percentage of Internet users have referrers turned off?

Tags: referrer

I'm making something that requires me to pass information from one domain to a subdomain. The subdomain would be in an iframe on the domain. I know I can use cookies, sessions, or a database. But I'm trying to save processing time so I thought about using the referrer. I know that some people turn the referrer off for some reason, but exactly just how many. If they do, this won't work for them.

Oh and I can't use the URL to pass information.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257609/which-browsers-plugins-block-httpreferer-from-being-sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say < 0.001 % of all Internet users have ever heard about referrers. Even a smaller portion of them will be willing to switch them off. Even a smaller number of them will be able to.

Comment: Source? My guess would be low, too, but I have no idea whether it's more like 10%, 1%, 0.1%, or 0.001% as you say.